How Can I change profile picture for unlicensed user in Microsoft SharePoint admin
I am currently facing an issue where an unlicensed user in our SharePoint environment is unable to change their profile picture. I would like to know if it’s possible to modify the profile picture for unlicensed users, and if so, could you please guide me through the necessary steps to resolve this issue?
I want to change profile picture for unlicensed user in SharePoint.

I'm afraid it is not possible to change profile picture for unlicensed users.
